# Track pageview, event, custom var to Google Analytics using PHP?

Tags: php, google-analytics

I would like to know the way (if possible) of Google Analytics tracking (pageviews, events, custom vars) using a **PHP calls** (using `POST`/`GET` with `cURL` or other methods) instead of JavaScript.

The problem is our client want to track some special events that are unable to track using JavaScript or I would have to set special (and generally useless) `SESSION` variables to check if set and then track using JavaScript and unset them that would lead into nasty code in templates...

I saw some PHP [project](http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/) that should provide such a functionality, but I would like to have it in pure PHP as I am not allowed to integrate such a third-party project into mine.

So my question: **Is there a way of tracking Google Analytics from within a PHP code in controllers instead of JavaScript code in templates?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php-ga does exactly what you are looking for. There's an awful lot of variables for the URL building to keep track of for sending your own requests. If you want to dig into and make it yourself - the library you posted is a really good place cause the parts of the URL are easily explained by the code around it.

Comment: There is no developer documentation nor wiki so I do not even know how to use it. Anyway as I mentioned - **I am not allowed to use such a third-party code within my current project**...

Comment: It's open source. Take a look at the internal folder and the request classes. There the URLs are built from explanatory function names so you can see how to build your own.